# Passing a macro defined by \newrobustcmd to another macro causes some problems while \DeclareRobustCommand doesn't!

Tags: expansion, robust-commands

I wrote a macro for slicing any part of string. It works with ordinary strings but when a string defined with \newrobustcmd passed to it, the macro doesn't work and causes error. (in case of using \DeclareRobustCommand there is no problem.) I'm so confused why it happens? 
Both \DeclareRobustCommand and \newrobustcmd are creating robust command, but why they act different?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\slice[#1,#2]#3{
    \newcount\cwords \cwords=1
    \newcount\cstart \cstart=#1
    \advance\cstart by -1\relax
    \def\sentece{}
    \def\empty{}
    \edef\tail{#3\space}
    \def\extract ##1 ##2;{
        \edef\tail{##2}
        \ifnum\cwords>\cstart
            \ifnum\cwords<#2
                \edef\sentece{\sentece\space##1}
            \fi
        \fi            
        \advance\cwords by 1\relax
    }
    \expandafter\extract\tail;
    \loop
        \expandafter\extract\tail;
        \unless\ifx\tail\empty
    \repeat
    \sentece
}

\begin{document}
%    \DeclareRobustCommand\x[1]{This is a test sentece. #1}
%    \DeclareRobustCommand\y{\x{end}}
    \newrobustcmd\x[1]{This is a test sentece. #1}
    \newrobustcmd\y{\x{end}}    
    \slice[3,5]\y
\end{document}
```

P.S. How can fully expand a robust macro?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are completely different forms of protection,

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\foo{xxx}
```

defines `\foo` to be `\protect\foox` and this will expand in an `\edef` unless `\protect` is locally defined (eg to `\noexpand`) so in your `\edef\tail{#3\space}` it fully expands.

The second definition is essentially

```
\protected\def\foo{xxx}
```

using the e-tex `\protected` primitive, this defines commands that do not expand in `\edef` and the latex `\protect` mechanism is not used.

Note that `\newcount` should be outside your definition as you do not want to allocate new registers on each use. Also all the lines ending `}` or `{` should have `%` to avoid generating spurious spaces in the output.

Comment: Thanks for immediate answer. In second case --using \protected-- how can expand it?

Comment: @javadr basically, you can't. If you know the protected macro is the first thing you can expand it one step with `\expandafter` but `\protected` macros in the body of your string are basically unexpandable. Note also that while your example happens to work in an `\edef` in general it will not work, most commands that are made robust would give errors in an edef which is why they are made robust (and then in latex you would use `\protected@edef` which sets up `\protect` before the `\edef`

Comment: Do you mean there isn't anyway to copy the content of \y macro --after expansion-- to another expandable macro?!

Comment: @javadr you can expand it one step `\expandafter\def\expandafter\newy\expandafter{\y}` but that (apart from losing `\protected`) is more or less the same as `\let\newy=\y` but in general there is no "full expansion".  If you attempt to do that with `\edef`, then  commands defined using `\protect` will typically give errors and commands defined with `\protected` simply don't expand.